# How to join to 2 different tables based on field value of main table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I have 3 tables named `menus`, `products` and `categories`.

menus table has id, item_type which can be product|category and item_id.

What I'd like to do is when `menu item_type = product`, join it with the products table `ON products.id = menu.item_id` and join with `categories when item_type = category`.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT m.* FROM menus m 
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.id = m.item_id AND m.item_type = 'product' 
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = m.item_id AND m.item_type = 'category'
```

The query works though I'm not seeing any product or category data attached to each menu.

Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `SELECT` the columns that you want.  You are only selecting columns from the `menus` table, so that is all you get.

I would suggest selecting columns from the other two tables, but combining them using `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT m.*,
       COALESCE(p.name, c.name) as name,  -- or whatever the columns are
       -- repeat for additional columns that you want
FROM menus m LEFT JOIN
     products p
     ON p.id = m.item_id AND m.item_type = 'product' LEFT JOIN
     categories c
     ON c.id = m.item_id AND m.item_type = 'category'
```

Comment: While the other answers worked... this is what I needed to. I want to display the product or category name as one field only and using COALESCE(p.name, c.name) as name did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You are selecting only the values in menu by using a `SELECT m.*`

The correct query is to just use * or the fields you require specifically.

```
SELECT * FROM menus m 
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.id = m.item_id AND m.item_type = 'product' 
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = m.item_id AND m.item_type = 'category'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the fields of the tables to `JOIN` with as well, since you're only selecting the fields of the `m` table.

Eventually you might also need to make your joins `OUTER` to still include records that don't match to any of your 2 joins: e.g.: menus with another `item_type` *(which is not your actual use case, as I can see now, btw)*

```sql
SELECT m.*, p.*, c.* FROM menus m 
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.id = m.item_id AND m.item_type = 'product' 
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = m.item_id AND m.item_type = 'category'
```

Should be sufficient enough to return all of your `menu` records, some of them with only product info (`NULL` values for category fields) and viceversa:

- p.* values with `NULL`s when item_type=category
- c.* values with `NULL`s when item_type=menu